# Why am I getting a load error when I try to use gem commands on my Mac?

Tags: mac, ruby

I am trying to install sass on my mac, but every time I try to use any gem command like `gem install sass` or `gem update --system` I get the following errors:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

This also happens when I try to install homebrew.

My ruby version using `ruby -v` gives

```
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

I am using macOS 10.14.2.

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a short term solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328019/cannot-load-such-file-rubygems-rb

Installing rvm and doing this above worked for me.

My usr/bin/ruby is still not working, so I would assume isn't a full fix for the system ruby. `ruby` works for me now. I wasn't able to install brew before, but now I am able to.